# SortableJS not working on my website when visiting on mobile - almost crashes the mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I'm a newbie here and a development beginner so any help would be great :)

### **SITUATION**

I've built a website with SortableJS library to use drag'n'drop functionalities on a list of rearrangeable items.
The idea of the website is to help music labels and vinyl enthusiasts to build their perfect tracklisting by rearranging titles.

### **ELEMENTS**

code: https://github.com/saint-james-fr/vinyl-tracklisting
demo: https://www.maxencerobinet.fr/vinyl-tracklisting/

### **PROBlEM**

Since then, I was working on my own local repo and testing with my browser. I've recently uploaded my work to GitHub so I started visiting the website on mobile - but it made my browser crashes + none of the drag-and-drop functionalities are working.
Can someone may have a look at my code to find what's going on?

### **HYPOTHESIS**

Also, to handle the rearranging by the users I'm using this bit of code that in my opinion is a bit too massive. Initial goal was to make sure any changes in the DOM arborescence will launch functions to calculate and reinitialize tracks orders. Ex: moving track A3 to A1 => A3 becomes A1 etc.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
  updatePosition("sideA");
  updatePosition("sideB");
  length("sideA");
  length("sideB");
  });
});
mutationObserver.observe(document.documentElement, {
  attributes: true,
  characterData: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributeOldValue: true,
  characterDataOldValue: true
});        
    }, false);
```

Maybe this bit of code crashes my browser on mobile... Or something else!
I'm testing on Android Chrome 105.0.5195.79

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Problem: actual code not working on mobile devices and making the browser crash despite working well on desktops.